# Div class only hidden in jQuery Tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have come across a strange problem which I do not know how to fix. I have implemented tabs using a jQuery plugin [Tabulous] and am in the progress of shifting pre-existing content into the tabs. I have come acrross a strange problem when trying to position an image to the left of a block-quote of text.

As you can see in the image below the image and text displays successfully outside of the 'tab' however placing the same code and styling inside the tab results in the following. Using inspect element I have checked and the iamge div is present in the correct location but the image appears to be hidden behind another element.

[image: Current Website View]

Here is the relevant HTML code- there are several tabs within  the tabs_container div

```
<div id="tabs_container">
    <div id="tabs-1">         
    jdlfgbkfdjgn
    <div class="trainer-container">
        <div id="Adrienne"></div>
            <div class="h3light">Adrienne Michowski</div>
            <div class="post-thumb"><img src="images/person3.jpg" width="200" height="200"></div>
            <blockquote class="trainer">
                An English mathematician and writer, chiefly known for her work on Charles Babbage's early mechanical general-purpose computer, the Analytical Engine. Her notes on the engine include what is recognised as the first algorithm intended to be carried out by a machine. Because of this, she is often regarded as the first computer programmer. She trains clients in programming and longevity.
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS code used:

```
#tabs_container {
padding: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: white;
border-right: 5px solid #861b3f;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:0;
align: left;
/*width: 100%;*/}

.trainer-container {
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom: 30px;}


h3 {
font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Segoe,sans-serif;
padding: 1px 0 14px 0;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 20px;}

.h3light {
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
padding: 0.3em;
margin-bottom: 15px;
text-indent: 20px;
/* Box Shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #D53369;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #D53369;
/*box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #FFF;*/}

.post-thumb {
display: block;
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
z-index: 1;
clear: both;
background: none;}

/* Blockquotes */

blockquote {
background: #fff;
padding: 15px 20px 15px 45px;
margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
height: auto;
font-family: Georgia,serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.2;
color: #000;
text-align: justify;
border-left: 20px solid #861b3f;
border-right: 5px solid #861b3f;
/* Box Shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #861b3f;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #861b3f;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #861b3f;
/*opacity: 0.5;*/
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}

blockquote::before {
font-family: Georgia,serif;
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #999;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 5px;}

blockquote::after {
content: "";}

blockquote.trainer {
min-height: 170px;
margin: 0 0 0 220px;}
```

Even using clear: both and z-indexing I cannot get the image to appear to the user. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: The image which you said seems hidden didn't load for me. Not sure if that's related to the issue.  Try taking `overflow:hidden` off of the image. Also, try adding `float:none;` to the image.

Comment: Your posted markup seems to work fine. Please provide minimal code which reproduces the issue. You may find using something like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is helpful in setting up an example.

Answer (score 0):

add class called 'tabDiv' to tabs-# l div,

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="tabDiv">
     <p class="h3light">Adrienne Michowski</p>
     <div class="post-thumb"><img src="RioOlympic.png" width="200" height="200"></div>
        <blockquote class="trainer">
        An English mathematician and writer, chiefly known for her work on Charles Babbage's early mechanical general-purpose computer, the Analytical Engine. Her notes on the engine include what is recognised as the first algorithm intended to be carried out by a machine. Because of this, she is often regarded as the first computer programmer. She trains clients in programming and longevity.
</blockquote>  

</div>
```

because following code in tabulous.Js does not work for nested or multiple divs

```
  if (this.options.effect == 'scale') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescale');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'slideLeft') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideleft');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'scaleUp') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescaleup');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'flip') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideflip');
    }
```

instead of that use class name called 'tabclass' to apply css

```
  var tabclass = ".tabDiv";

 if (this.options.effect == 'scale') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find(tabclass).not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescale');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'slideLeft') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find(tabclass).not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideleft');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'scaleUp') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find(tabclass).not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescaleup');
    } else if (this.options.effect == 'flip') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find(tabclass).not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideflip');
    }
 var alldivs = $('#tabs_container').find(tabclass);
```

output print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF7Dd.png

reference from @ingro comment: https://github.com/aarondo/tabulous.js/issues/7